# Disable NextJs ISG caching when there is get query in url

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Lets suppose there are three urls

```
url1 = 'https://example.com/products'
url2 = 'https://example.com/products?q=car'
url3 = 'https://example.com/products?q=bike'
```

I am using NextJs ISG and getting same list of products on these urls.

#### products.jsx

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const url = new URL(ApiEndPoint);

  const q = context?.query?.q;
  if (q)
    url.searchParams.append("q", q);

  const { data } = await fetch(url.href).then(r => r.json());

  return { props: { products: data, query: q }, revalidate: 1800 }; // 30 mins
};
```

#### packagejson

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.7",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.12",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.1",
    "github-slugger": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1"
  }
```